# Repeated Record - Nested and Repeated Data - Java API

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to stream repeated record field using JAVA API. It inserts the record but with null values. The data and schema I am using is from google's example for "Nested and Repeated Data"

Following is the code snippet:

```
      TableRow row = new TableRow();
      row.set("kind", "person");
      row.set("fullName", "P");
      row.set("age", "22");
      row.set("gender", "M");


      TableRow prow = new TableRow();
      prow.set("areaCode", 206);
      prow.set("number", 1234567);       
      row.set("phoneNumber", prow);

      JsonArray children = new JsonArray();

      JsonObject child1 = new JsonObject();
      child1.addProperty("name", "Jane");
      child1.addProperty("gender", "f");
      child1.addProperty("age", 6);       
      children.add(child1);

      JsonObject child2 = new JsonObject();
      child2.addProperty("name", "John");
      child2.addProperty("gender", "m");
      child2.addProperty("age", 15);          
      children.add(child2);

      row.set("children", children);


      TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows rows = new TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows();         
      rows.setJson(row);

      List  rowList = new ArrayList();
      rowList.add(rows);
      TableDataInsertAllRequest content = new TableDataInsertAllRequest().setRows(rowList);
      TableDataInsertAllResponse response = bigquery.tabledata().insertAll(projectId, "tmp", "person5", content).execute();
```

Comment: Are you printing the errors from the response? I think the issue is with the JsonObject, try to use there `TableRow` as in `prow`, or `row`.

Comment: If i do that then it throws an error that "JsonArray is required"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of JsonArray creating List is working as below:

```
List<TableRow> children = new ArrayList<TableRow>();

TableRow child1 = new TableRow();
child1.set("name", "Jane");
child1.set("gender", "f");
child1.set("age", 6);       

TableRow child2 = new TableRow();
child2.set("name", "John");
child2.set("gender", "m");
child2.set("age", 15);

children.add(child1);
children.add(child2);
```